# Running proj/cs2cs command in Powershell

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, proj, cs2cs, powershell

I'm reading a book where it says to run the following in the commandline, I think he used Linux. Therefore the command doesn't run in Windows Powershell

```
cs2cs +proj=latlong +datum=NAD83 +to +proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=NAD27 -r <<EOF
45d15’33.1" 111.5W
45d15.551666667N -111d30
+45.25919444444 111d30’000w
EOF
```

[image]

When ran, Powershell says

> The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
> + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingFileSpecification

[image]

How do I run the command in Powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [here-string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1#here-strings) and pipe "|" to `cs2cs` (note you must have a new line immediately after the opening `@"` and before the closing `"@`)

```
echo @"
45d15'33.1" 111.5W
45d15.551666667N -111d30
+45.25919444444 111d30'000w
"@ | cs2cs +proj=latlong +datum=NAD83 +to +proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=NAD27 -r
```

Or add the coordinates to a file (e.g coords.txt) and pass that as an argument

```
cs2cs +proj=latlong +datum=NAD83 +to +proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=NAD27 -r coords.txt
```

Comment: It worked. Now I understand the syntax.